# How to create java classes from WSDL file and use it in our Android application?

Tags: android, web-services

I'm new to web services. Can any one explain How to generate java classes from WSDL file using apache axis2 (or any other tool) and how to use those classes in our android application to call the web service methods with an example...

Comment: in that, they are calling the web service methods directly using the SOAP without generating stub class. My requirement is to generate the client stub class means to generate the java classes from wsdl file and use those java classes to call the web service methods.

Comment: check this http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL

Answer (score 0):

Download and use this library: [ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.0.0/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

Then use this method to call methods from the web service:

```
public String method(String input)
{
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService/";
    final String URL = "http://...Service.svc";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "NAME OF THE METHOD";

    try
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        //Repeat this line for each input parameter
        request.addProperty("NAME OF THE INPUT", input);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
        return envelope.getResponse().toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Note: This method may not be called on the GUI thread.

Comment: in the above you are calling the web service methods directly using the SOAP without generating stub class. My requirement is to generate the client stub class means to generate the java classes from wsdl file (using wsdltojava.bat of apache axis2 tool) and use those java classes to call the web service methods